# How is this the correct representation of the given nested structure [SICP]? What am I missing?

Tags: list, nested, scheme, sicp

Second sentence of [Section 2.2.2 (Hierarchical Structures)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.2) of SICP: the authors say that `((1 2) 3 4)` (a list of three elements) can be constructed by `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`.

I think (wrongly so, of course) that it will construct `((1 2) (3 4))` (two elements) instead because:

1. `3` and `4` will be enclosed in a nested `list` not in the top-level `cons`, and
2. `cons` constructs a pair of items, and pair means 2 elements not 3.

What am I failing to understand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is a chain of pairs, ending with a pair whose `cdr` is the empty list.

`(list 3 4)` is two pairs, equivalent to

```
                 (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))
```

So `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` is 3 pairs, equivalent to

```
(cons (list 1 2) (cons 3 (cons 4 '())))
```

In general, if you have a list `old-list`, you can create a new list with a new element on the front with:

```
(cons new-element old-list)
```

You would get what you expected if you wrote

```
(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```